# Problem with Profile2 and NodeAccess

Tags: users

We use Profile2 and Node Access but the profiles of users can't be show by everyone (access denied)  since we have installed Node Access. The problem is the same with Content Access.
Do you know how we can see profile of users and use Node Access or Content Access ( we want to limit access on pages of our intranet's ?
Thank you.

Comment: can an Admin view the profiles? can an authenticated user view their own profile?

Comment: Yes, when you are an authenticated user, you can see all user profiles and you can edit your own profile. We have created a directory with profiles of users : we have a view that listed all users with a link to see their profil. But with node access, we don't have the link et we can't access to read profiles when you are not authenticated. We want authenticated users  to create their profile and this profile to be read by every body (anonymous and authenticated users)

Comment: never worked with Content Access with profile2 - but some things to look into: according to the documentation - "Note that users need at least the access content permission to be able to deal in any way with published content." if not set, see if that changes anything.  Next, when viewing the profile type, is there a new tab at the top for content access (by manage fields, manage display, etc)?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Finally we use a taxomony and Taxomony Access Control and we don't have the problem !

Comment: glad you found a solution - be sure to include that as an answer and 'accept' it, so this question doesn't remain unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. Finally we use a taxomony and Taxomony Access Control and we don't have the problem !
We create a vocabulary : Intranet with two words Private and Public. And we use Taxomony Access Control